# How to restart Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

How do I restart an Android `Activity`?  I tried the following, but the `Activity` simply quits.

```
public static void restartActivity(Activity act){

        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setClass(act, act.getClass());
        act.startActivity(intent);
        act.finish();

}
```

Comment: the activity quits because u called "act.finish();" immediately after creating the activity...

Comment: outdated method

Comment: use `recreate()` for Re-Load or Re-Launch Activity.

Answer (score 682):

I did my theme switcher like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Basically, I'm calling `finish()` first, and I'm using the exact same intent this activity was started with. That seems to do the trick?

UPDATE: As pointed out by Ralf below, [`Activity.recreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) is the way to go in API 11 and beyond. This is preferable if you're in an API11+ environment. You can still check the current version and call the code snippet above if you're in API 10 or below. (Please don't forget to upvote Ralf's answer!)

Comment: the problem w/ this approach is that it animates the activity so it appears to slide in and out...

Comment: Well, if you don't like the animation, you can turn it off (as you demonstrated in your answer). That doesn't make my answer wrong per se, it's just not showing some additional options that you are free to add (and that wasn't asked for in the question).

Comment: i never said you'r answer was wrong, a down vote doesn't necessarily mean wrong, its just not as good as another.  not trying to toot my own horn here, just saying that not showing the animation gives a truer "refresh" experience from a UX perspective.

Comment: I think you got that wrong. A downvote means wrong/bad answer, and upvote means an answer is great. How great an answer is compared to others is indicated by the number of upvotes. I can see that you're trying to promote your answer, but you're misusing the system for that purpose.

Comment: well i dont want to go on arguing this with you, lets agree to disagree.  i think the voting provides a way to rank answers, you dont.  we'll leave it at that.  you're answer actually is decent, it just looks weird because of the animation flying in and out, I can't imagine any scenario where I'd want to have that effect.  it looks like you're leaving the page, and then coming right back to it.

Comment: +1 - this worked great for me, and as you say, the animation is something i did want, so the user knows it is restarting.  FWIW, I make it a rule never to down-vote other users answers when I provide an alternate answer to the question, although I do occasionally up-vote when my answer is outclassed (not saying that happened here, just that I do it).

Comment: EboMike and Ben: Both of your solutions answered the OP's question. To vote down someone's answer purely because of "aesthetic" reason is, well, not great. I would discourage anyone from doing it here at Stackoverflow...

Comment: what if the previous activity called this one using startActivityForResult ?

Comment: sometimes (on Android 6.1) it gives `java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start activity Intent`

Comment: based on experiment the difference is `recreate` will call onDestroy before starting new activity. manually starting the activity and finishing the current one does not. you must make sure every thing is closed before starting new activity manually.

Answer (score 401):

Since API level 11 (Honeycomb), you can call the [recreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) method of the activity (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7858127/214837) answer).

The recreate() method acts just like a configuration change, so your onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods are also called, if applicable.

Comment: what if the previous activity called this one using startActivityForResult ?

Comment: Well, it's the correct answer if you don't need to support anything lower than API 11.

Comment: @EdwardFalk is there any function that does it on the support library?

Comment: This does not work in all cases. If you have a navigation drawer open while calling recreate() it will stay open when recreated, which means it saves the state, which may not be desirable.

Comment: I'm the one who don't want the state to be saved. Sometimes people just want a clean restart, then they should use EboMike's answer.

Comment: after calling recreate() method onBackPressed() method is not calling.

Answer (score 140):

Before SDK 11, a way to do this is like so:

```
public void reload() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: On HTC Desire animations still remain (at least when used in onConfigurationChanged method). They don't occur always, but using EboMike's code they also don't occur always.

Comment: This doesn't work on the main activity started by the launcher. Your activity will end up hidden because of some of the flags set on the intent. Otherwise it works nicely.

Comment: Good point.  makes sense because it calls finish() from the base activity in the stack.

Comment: Calling this while we change the theme of the Activity seems to bring out the speed (without animations)

Comment: +1 Works fine, for me even with the main Activity. However, you should call `overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` after `finish()` and `startActivity()`, respectively, not where you called it ...

Comment: @MarcoW. is correct, check the docs for `overridePendingTransition()`.

Comment: what if the previous activity called this one using startActivityForResult ?

Comment: yeah that would not behave properly then.  @Ralf's answer below is now the way you should do this.

Answer (score 117):

Just to combine Ralf and Ben's answers (including changes made in comments):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    recreate();
} else {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Best answer of all. Believe it or not though, I'm still supporting API 3 devices, and the VERSION.SDK_INT value requires API 4. :)

Answer (score 39):

I used this code so I still could support older Android versions and use `recreate()` on newer Android versions.

Code:

```
public static void restartActivity(Activity activity){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        activity.recreate();
    } else {
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(activity.getIntent());
    }
}
```

Sample:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mActivity = MainActivity.this;

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restart_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                restartActivity(mActivity);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void restartActivity(Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            activity.recreate();
        } else {
            activity.finish();
            activity.startActivity(activity.getIntent());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

This is by far the easiest way to restart the current activity:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Answer (score 26):

I wonder why no one mentioned `Intent.makeRestartActivityTask()` which cleanly makes this exact purpose.

> Make an Intent that can be used to re-launch an application's task
>        * in its base state.

```
startActivity(Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(getActivity().getIntent().getComponent()));
```

This method sets `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` as default flags.

Answer (score 24):

This solution worked for me.

First finish the activity and then start it again.

Sample code:

```
public void restartActivity(){
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(mIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Call this method

```
private void restartFirstActivity()
 {
 Intent i = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
 .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName() );

 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
 startActivity(i);
 }
```

Thanks,

Comment: I think the OP wants to restart any activity, not just the first one, but this was helpful to me.

Comment: The two flags are good to know, my case seemed to do nothing without them.

Answer (score 16):

Even though this has been answered multiple times.

If restarting an activity from a fragment, I would do it like so:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run()
         {
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            getActivity().finish();

            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

So you might be thinking this is a little overkill?
But the `Handler` posting allows you to call this in a lifecycle method. I've used this in `onRestart`/`onResume` methods when checking if the state has changed between the user coming back to the app. (installed something).

Without the `Handler` if you call it in an odd place it will just kill the activity and not restart it.

Feel free to ask any questions.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Great solution and very good reasoning/explanation for the Handler.

Comment: Why do you call twice to "overridePendingTransition" ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I can't remember, I think it was a work around to a bug. You can call it once before startActivity() and it will do as told.

Comment: After implementing this in my onResume function, the game stops on my onStop method and has a black screen... not sure why

Comment: @Scumble373 that could be due to many many reasons. We finish the activity here then start it again. it could be OpenGL throwing a wobbly, well out of scope on this question/answer. I recommend you open a new question and reference this answer.

Comment: Hi chris, can you explain this a bit further "Without the Handler if you call it in an odd place it will just kill the activity and not restart it." ?

Answer (score 15):

Well this is not listed but a combo of some that is already posted:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    recreate();   
} else {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: It works for me .. thanks .. but I want to ask you: why when i remove the first part of the code (the one that checks the SDK_INT) my app runs, relatively, slow ?!! .. when I re-attach the code again it runs, relatively and obviously, much faster !!!

Comment: Not sure on that.  Well, if you are using an SDK that is >= 11 then recreate() should be faster than getting intent, finishing, then starting it again.

Finish calls code that runs to onStop and recreate runs code like orientation change... so it's not quite as much to do.

Answer (score 14):

If anybody is looking for Kotlin answer you just need this line.

**Fragment**

```
startActivity(Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(activity?.intent?.component))
```

**Activity**

```
startActivity(Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(this.intent?.component))
```

Answer (score 4):

There is one hacky way that should work on any activity, including the main one.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

When orientation changes, Android generally will recreate your activity (unless you override it). This method is useful for 180 degree rotations, when Android doesn't recreate your activity.

Answer (score 4):

In conjunction with [strange SurfaceView lifecycle behaviour with the Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495842/how-surfaceholder-callbacks-are-related-to-activity-lifecycle). I have found that recreate() does not behave well with the lifecycle of SurfaceViews. surfaceDestroyed isn't ever called during the recreation cycle. It is called after onResume (strange), at which point my SurfaceView is destroyed.

The original way of recreating an activity works fine.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

I can't figure out exactly why this is, but it is just an observation that can hopefully guide others in the future because it fixed my problems i was having with SurfaceViews

Answer (score 4):

The solution for your question is:

```
public static void restartActivity(Activity act){
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setClass(act, act.getClass());
    ((Activity)act).startActivity(intent);
    ((Activity)act).finish();
}
```

You need to cast to activity context to start new activity and as well as to finish the current activity.

Hope this helpful..and works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the following code is valid for API levels 5 and up, so if your target API is lower than this, you'll end up with something very similar to EboMike's code.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setClass(act, act.getClass());
    finish();
    act.startActivity(intent);
}
```

try to use this ..

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the last line, you'll create new `act` Activity, but your old instance will still be alive.

Do you need to restart the Activity like when the orientation is changed (i.e. your state is saved and passed to `onCreate(Bundle)`)?

If you don't, one possible workaround would be to use one extra, dummy Activity, which would be started from the first Activity, and which job is to start new instance of it. Or just delay the call to `act.finish()`, after the new one is started.

If you need to save most of the state, you are getting in pretty deep waters, because it's non-trivial to pass all the properties of your state, especially without leaking your old Context/Activity, by passing it to the new instance.

Please, specify what are you trying to do.

Comment: I have a button that applies different themes to the app, after the theme is applied, it's saved in preference, the root activity restarts, reads the theme from preference, applies the theme in onCreate().  It turns out that the above code works fine if the activity is not single_instance.   Not sure if that's the best practice.

Comment: Currently, there is no clean, SDK-paved way to restart your Activity, AFAIK - if you don't leak anything, you may be good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin way:

```
fun Activity.restartActivity() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        recreate()
    } else {
        finish()
        startActivity(getIntent())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is

```
    public void restartActivity(){
    Intent i = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are calling from some fragment so do below code.

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
getActivity().finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the way I do it.

```
        val i = Intent(context!!, MainActivity::class.java)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        startActivity(i)
```

Answer (score -5):

Call the method onCreate. For example `onCreate(null);`