# Reload current activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I my Android app to refresh its current activity on ButtonClick.

I have a button on the top of the activity layout which should do the job. When I click on the button, the current activity should reload, just like a device restart.

How can I do that?

Comment: [for API before 11 you cannot use recreate(). I solved in this way:][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486934/programmatically-relaunch-recreate-an-activity

Comment: it's already answered here with a good approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/6283098/8713823

Answer (score 130):

```
public void onClick (View v){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I had this code with me but it basically shows animation that we are moving from one activity to another. And also my previous activity is still alive. i want everything should be loaded again.

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);`

Comment: That is important thanks @Otra

Comment: My listView is not getting refreshed with this method. Why?

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this,YourActivity.class);
finish();
startActivity(intent);`

Best Solution it will refresh every  thing . ofc if you want to save some data you can use shared Pref before finishing the page @Otra @Shine

Answer (score 37):

You may try this

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

This question was asked before:
[How do I restart an Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity)

Comment: I had this code with me but it basically shows animation that we are moving from one activity to another. And also my previous activity is still alive. i want everything should be loaded again.

Comment: From your own question "It should start again and delete all the instances of previous current activity." That is what @Greg's answer does

Comment: If you don't want the activity loading animation. Figure out what you want to refresh and do it manually.

Answer (score 29):

In an activity you can call `recreate()` to "recreate" the activity
(API 11+)

Comment: Works like charm, thank you for the solution!

Comment: This one works! It has no animation!

Comment: awesome... but can we remove black out animation while recreating.

Answer (score 12):

This is a refresh button method, but it works well in my application. in finish() you kill the instances

```
public void refresh(View view){          //refresh is onClick name given to the button
    onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    Intent i = new Intent(lala.this, lala.class);  //your class
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}
```

Comment: this will only work if your current intent has no data from any previous intent.

Answer (score 9):

this is what worked for me as seen [here](http://appglobe.com/restart-an-activity-android).

Just use it or add it to a static class helper and just call it from anywher in your project.

```
/**
Current Activity instance will go through its lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it.
*/
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
  public static final void recreateActivityCompat(final Activity a) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      a.recreate();
    } else {
      final Intent intent = a.getIntent();
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
      a.finish();
      a.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
      a.startActivity(intent);
      a.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: after putting this... the activity keeps restarting itself.

Comment: @AbuRuqaiyah make sure you are calling this in an onClickListener or whatever trigger you want. Also make sure you are not calling this function from a loop or a function that might be executed each time your app starts up-- hope you understood the process

Comment: Thanks, this is worked for me

Answer (score 4):

> It should start again and delete all the instances of previous current activity.

No, it shouldn't.

It should update its data in place (e.g., `requery()` the `Cursor`). Then there will be no "instances of previous current activity" to worry about.

Comment: Can u pls little more elaborate...In my activity one asynchronus thread is running in background. when i want to reoload this activity this asynchronus thread instance is not deleted and even two instances are created one previous and one new...

Comment: @Vivek_Android_Developer: You are the one forking the thread. When you refresh your UI, do not start a second thread.

Comment: I ll check dat..and will let you know..

Comment: @CommonsWare But what if you user clicks a stale piece of information in the time between resuming the old activity and updating the cursor backed view?

Comment: @mattblang: If that is a danger, clear the old data upon resuming, put up a `ProgressBar` or other indicator, then load in the fresh `Cursor` when it becomes available.

Answer (score 4):

You can Try this:

```
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);         
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();        
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();        
        Intent intent= new Intent(YourCurrent.this, YourCurrent.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
startActivity(MyClass.this, MyClass.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to refresh an Activity from within itself.

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to call `onCreate(null);` and your activity will be like new.

Comment: That sounds rather dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this

Simple way

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(Current_Activity.this,Current_Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best choice for you is using SwipeRefreshLayout View in your layout.
Then set RefreshListener like.

```
mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    Log.i("Fav ", "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");

                    // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
                    // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
                    request();  // call what you want to update in this method
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
    );
```

For more details [click this link](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can call this method:

```
recreate();
```

Answer (score 0):

From  dialog to activity that you want to refresh. If it not first activity! 
Like this:**mainActivity**>>**objectActivity**>>**dialog**
In your dialog class:

```
  @Override
public void dismiss() {
    super.dismiss();
   getActivity().finish();
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), objectActivity.class);  //your class
    startActivity(i);

}
```