# Android: Update WiFi propertys

Tags: android, wifi

I have various WiFi propertys displayed in my app, such as SSID and the RSSI (signal strength). I have made a class which stores these informations, named Router, it is responsible for getting the propertys and modifying them for TextViews inside a Fragment. I would like to use a Refresh Button, how could I achieve the actual refresh? I tried to just run through the constructor again, but this seems unprofessional, slow, and not working... (BTW I'm using WifiInfo and DHCPInfo and such). I thought of a Thread to handle this.. Will this work? There should be refreshments on button click and refreshments on a user's choice time interval, like every 10 sec.. The next thing I thought of was a BroadcastReceiver, but there's no controllable refreshment. Is it better to let the user choose the time interval or just update the data based on the BroadcastReceiver? Is it possible to refresh this with a single click on a button? I want these refreshments to be fast, and not dependent from the main thread.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By rerunning the constructor, do you mean the activity's onCreate() or the Router constructor? If nthe first one is not the slow alternative you maybe would like to refresh your activity to update your information. Then you should take a look at the responses to this question: [Android refresh current activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547969/android-refresh-current-activity)

I don't know enough about threads to give you advise concerning this topic. I am sorry about that.

I think that a BroadcastReceiver would be the most user friendly alternative because it does everthing for the user on its own. Otherwise if you for example use a button for refreshing your app, it would need the user's active participation to fulfill its purpose.