# Problems with refreshing list view after deleting the item

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

I have a ListView with items on the left, and fragment displaying item details on the right. Now when user long presses the item on the left there's an option to delete the selected item. Now when I delete it I have to change the activity then come back to it to see the change it doesn't refresh the list automatically.

I have tried implementing `notifyDataSetChanged()` and some other methods with invalidating the list but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

I set the list adapter in `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<NoteContent.Note>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1, 
            noteContent.getListOfNotes());
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And now I would have to update it when the delete button is clicked:

```
case R.id.action_delete:
// Deleting the item.
NoteContent.Note noteToDelete = new NoteContent.Note();
noteToDelete = helper.getNote(noteContent.getListOfNotes().get(mActivatedPosition).getId());
                helper.deleteNote(noteToDelete);

// I guess the relevant code should go here but not sure.

mode.finish();
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

After deleting item just again call your activity...Again populate your list items.Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547969/android-refresh-current-activity).

```
             Intent intent = getIntent();
                 finish();
             startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: if I do that there's an animation of activities switching

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot.So we can understand it more.