# How to Update activity when open notification

Tags: java, android

I am working on **notification** and I have a problem. I have an activity already open when I click on notification I don't want to open it again just update the current activity.

```
if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
 Intent pushNotification = null;
                if (NotificationType != 0 && NotificationType != 2 && NotificationType != 5 && NotificationType != 26) {
                    pushNotification = new Intent(getApplication(), SplashScreen.class);
                    pushNotification.putExtra("NotificationType", NotificationType);
                    pushNotification.putExtra("ReferenceID", ReferenceID);
                    pushNotification.putExtra("NotificationID", ReferenceID);
                    pushNotification.putExtra("isread", ReferenceID);
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, time, pushNotification);
                } else if (NotificationType == 0 || NotificationType == 2 || NotificationType == 5 || NotificationType == 26) {
                    showNotificationMessageWithNoAction(getApplicationContext(), title, message, title, null);
                }
}
```

can Anyone tell me how I update the activity when I click on notification?

Comment: Have you checked this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547969/android-refresh-current-activity/#6547998

Comment: @SabbirAhmed i don't but i don't want to finish and restart it to again... i am looking for interaction or something like that which can be update my activity without restart.
thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare the `launchMode` to the **singleTask** to make ensure that multiple same screens not will open.

There are four launch modes for activity. They are:
1. Standard
2. SingleTop
3. SingleTask
4. SingleInstance

Please refer this link [Click here](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242)

```
<activity android:name="YOUR_SPLASH_ACTIVITY"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"

            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And in the `Java` code , you just override the **`onNewIntent`** method , to refresh `activity`,

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    /**
     * HERE YOU JUST REFRESH , YOUR ACTIVITY 
     */

}
```

Comment: ohh thanks its work after adding this code
android:launchMode="singleTask" &
 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            RefrenceId = intent.getIntExtra("ReferenceID", 0);
        }

Comment: You can also use the `intent. hasExtra("ReferenceID);`, for it.... happy to help you @MuhammadImran .. Keep happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you need but you can do this

```
  finish();
  startActivity(getIntent());
```

Let me know what you really need.

EDIT:

If you need to keep your activity state intact, you can do this

```
  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
 }
```

This will save your activity state

And then you retrieve UI state like this

```
  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
  }
```

Comment: i don't want to finish and restart it to again because i have too much network requests on start of activity that's why... i am looking for interaction or something like that which can be update my activity without restart. thank's

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to make use of the `onNewIntent(Intent)` method of your Activity.

You can use the **Intent** parameter of this method to get your **Intent Extras**, because `getIntent()` will give the Intent that started the Activity in the first place.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
    //Initial loading
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if(intent.getStringExtra("methodName").equals("myMethod")) {
            //Update the existing screen
        }
    }
}
```