# How to restart an activity with textview elements that are created dynamically?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Basically,I want to restart the activity ,each time the textview will display a different text that i have stored in a vector.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean... Can you give us more details?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486934/programmatically-relaunch-recreate-an-activity

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

public void recreate();

Note: Cause the Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a configuration change -- the current instance will go through its lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it.

Comment: This should be fine for what you want by calling this.recreate() for example, mark the answer as correct if did help you :)