# Recreating activity and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have Android application with two tabs. In first tab i have fragments of `Radio`. This fragments are created dynamically from settings. Number of this `Radio` fragments is from 0 to 6, depends.
In second tab I have `configurationFragment`'s one for each `Radio` and I can add new. After adding or editing I need to save this to configuration and I want to recreate activity and fragments. It seems that `recreate()` is recreating activity, creating new `Radio` fragments and `configurationFragment`'s but also old fragments still exists and call `onCreateView()` making some NullPointerExceptions.

How to recreate activity and destroy all old fragments and create new ones?

// SOLUTION

To properly recreate whole application just use `recreate()`. If you want also completly recreate your fragments, remember that your application will leave and try to use old fragments even if `RetainInstance` is false, just not save fields of Fragment(may throw some `NullPointerExceptions` if you using fields in `onCreateView` or other automatically called method from `Activity`), only views. You must detach fragments from `Activity` and normally create them again.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486934/programmatically-relaunch-recreate-an-activity

Comment: No good solution there. They just talking about `recreate()` it dont solve my problem.