# how to reflect instant change on activity android

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I am currently working on `calendar application` , in which when I add a event which is added in google calendar to show that event instantly on screen I am using `recreate()` method of activity which fetches all event and display it again but while this process screen turn in black , which is vary `bad UI experience` , how I can solve this issue , I want something like `google calendar` where events are instantly added. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your calendar uses an adapter for displaying items you can change the data in the adapter and invoke `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. It notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data will be refreshed with the new values from the adapter.

Comment: data not added to adapter it retrieved from calendar app

Answer (score 0):

Use `ProgressDialog` to keep the user "engaged" while you fetch new Calendar data and then take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486934/programmatically-relaunch-recreate-an-activity) Should give you an idea of how to `recreate` an Activity.

Comment: is there any good way like instant updating like in google calendar application

Comment: If the screen turns black, what happens afterwards?

Comment: actually I calling recreate() method of activity when new event is added to listview.

Comment: Okay look at my answer.I am editing to add a link to a question that does what you want.

Comment: Could you descrive your system more ? Where you are adding your events ? In the web and you want to Android get only inserted events ?  Or everything is working locally on Android device?

Comment: You need to try what i suggested in my answers first.Since you did not post your code,all i can do is assume.Try the solution in the link i added.I am confident that would solve your problem.Or post your code

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu , link you are mentioning is same as recreate activity I am asking for rather good way then recreate or calling the intent and finishing it ,,,