# Recreate Activity provoke black screen on android 9

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

When call `activity.recreate(`), there is a black screen (for 0.5 second). I don't know where it comes from since it was working fine on other devices

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52331896/4168607.

Answer (score -2):

use this

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Comment: It works but remember to free resources in the onDestroy method or you can get OutOfMemory Exception

Comment: but this does not help in a situation where you already have a stack of fragment loaded, this will recreate the activity but you lose the back stacks of the fragment ....

Answer (score -2):

try this

1. draw root view on bitmap
2. start second activity displaying that bitmap using custom fade animation
3. recreate first activity with delay = duration of fade animation
4. finish second activity