# Restart Activity onPostExecute

Tags: android, kotlin

I develop an aplication that reads a QR Barcode then parses JSON from the result of the barcode (Using AsyncTask).

If the result is true then the app moves to another activity (I achieve this). But if the result false **I want to restart the activity executed before from `onPostExecute`**.

What should I do in my app to restart an activity from `onPostExecute`?

Here is my code

```
override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
    super.onPostExecute(result)

    // parse json
    val parsJson = JSONObject (result)
    var result = parsJson.get("status")

    if (result == Izin.SUKSES){
        Toast.makeText(context,"Berhasil intent ke activity lain",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val intent = Intent(context,MainActivity::class.java)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Gagal Scan Ulang",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        // What should i do to restart activity
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically relaunch/recreate an activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486934/programmatically-relaunch-recreate-an-activity)

Comment: i tried this before, i cant accsess getIntent from onPostExecute nor using content.getIntent()

Comment: You don't need to access `getIntent` to recreate an activity ?

Comment: Just call `Activity#recreate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Simply use

```
startActivity(getIntent());
finish();
```

to refresh an Activity from within itself.

Alternatively you can call `recreate()` to refresh the activity.

Comment: You don't need to do this anymore. You can simply call `recreate()` on the activity, unless you are supporting devices lower than Honeycomb which is in-turn very impractical to me.

Comment: He is new so it would be easier to him.

Comment: @Qunata and @kelvin thaks for the answer.

i already solve my problem. im using `startActivity(getIntent)` which getIntent in kotlin (idk) i should **init** it in onCreate then i pass it on argumen in AsynTask parameter.

Thanks mates.

Comment: @MuhammadFarrasMa'ruf What you are passing in context?

Comment: @kelvin `this@Activity`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call `recreate` on your activity instance-

```kotlin
override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
    super.onPostExecute(result)

    ....

    if (result == Izin.SUKSES) {
        ....
    } else {
        activity.recreate()
    }
}
```

This already has a mention here: [Programmatically relaunch/recreate an activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486934/programmatically-relaunch-recreate-an-activity)