# Recreated activity returns home on back press, starting API 28

Tags: android, android-intent, launchmode

I observe an unwanted behavior starting Android Emulator API level 28 when I recreate an activity. On back press I'm getting on the home screen instead of the previous activity like below on API level 27 and below.

So the situation is as follows:

[image: class diagram]

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` the `MainActivity` is set as `singleTask`. Both the `MainActivity` and the `SettingsActivity` extend the `BaseActivity`.

In the `SettingsActivity` I let the user change to dark mode or another language and then I recreate the activity with:

```
getActivity().recreate();
```

The `BaseActivity` then recreates itself (approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52331896/)), if necessary according to the (new) preferences like:

```
startActivity(getIntent());
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

The recreation works fine. On **API level 27** and below I assume I get a task looking like the one on the **left** and from **API 28** upwards I assume I get one looking like the one on the **right**:

[image: task expected] [image: task actual]

But I would also expect a task looking like the first one for API 28 and upwards.

I figured out that in the `BaseActivity` I could add the [`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) Intent flag to recreate the activity if necessary which *gives* me the desired behavior but I don't understand why this actually helps and if this is the best thing to do here. Any Intent/Task expert here?

What do I miss here?

Comment: Strange. Have you tried this on any devices running API 28 or higher? Also, how do you know your task looks like this? What are you using to determine what activities are in the task?

Comment: No, I haven't tried this on any real device. I see this on the emulator. I do not know if the tasks look like this. I *assume* they look like that because of the behavior I see. On what I had a look is the `Activity Stack View` window in Android Studio. It didn't help me though.
I also found that the `NEW_TASK` flag had some work on it in API 28: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#fant-required but currently I see no relation to the issue I face.