# Restart all activities in task

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm implementing a setting to my app that allows the user to switch themes, the user will be in the settings activity when he switches the theme, and above it in the task will be the main screen.

I want the current `activity` to restart after the theme change, but I also want the main screen to restart, so when the user hits back from the settings page, he'll see the main screen with the new activity.

Restarting the current `activity` [is easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530473/how-do-i-restart-an-activity-in-android), but how do I force the previous `activities` in the current `task` to restart as well?

I've tried adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` / `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` to the `intent`, but it'll remove those activities from the `task`, so when I hit back from settings, I'm returned to the home screen and not to my app main screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to restart the main activity when the user returns to it?  Maybe, in `onActivityResult`?

Comment: That's a pretty good idea... I'll try it out.

Comment: As I think you know, system uses onConfigurationChange for that purpose. If system language will be changed - your activities will be either recreated, on onConfigurationChange() will be called, if you'll declare you can handle this case.
 
I think in your case you should try to do the same, however, I'm not  sure how to trigger COnfigurationChange due to your internal app setting. If it's possible to do so inside an app - it will be a perfect solution, I think.

Comment: @AleksG I've went with your solution, if you'd like to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @marmor Thanks. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way would be to restart the main activity when the user returns to it.  If you open your Preferences activity with `startActivityForResult`, then, when finishing that activity, you can use `setResult` to tell the main activity whether or not it needs to be restarted.  Finally, in the main activity's `onActivityResult` you can look at the passed result and restart the main activity if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can check if you have any configuration changes `onRestart` method, so when you press back, this method should be fired.

Comment: This seems to be working, but I worry my isThemeChanged method is a bit heavy, so I wouldn't want to call it on every onRestart. Anyway, this is definitely a correct answer, but I'm looking into alternative ways before accepting this as the one.