# Re-launch current activity using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launch

For an App I am developing, I want to re-launch the current activity using an intent. So I'm in MainActivity.class and I want to re-launch MainActivity.class using the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

This calls `onDestroy()` but does not re-launch the activity. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053761/reload-activity-in-android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If your are in an Activity:** `this.recreate();`

**If your are in a Fragment:** `getActivity.recreate();`

Related Links :

[How do I restart an Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity)

[how do I restart an activity in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530473/how-do-i-restart-an-activity-in-android)

[Android activity restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134249/android-activity-restart)

Answer (score 4):

You could just use:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Which will finish the current activity, and start a new activity with the same intent that you received when the activity was originally created. This should effectively re-launch the activity as is.

**Edit:**

See [Reload activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053761/reload-activity-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
  Intent i=getIntent();//This simply returns the intent in which the current Activity is started
  finish();//This would simply stop the current Activity.
  startActivity(i);//This would start a new Activity.
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this one ...

```
startActivity(intent);
```