# Android activity restart

Tags: android, android-activity, restart

I am having a confusion in restarting an activity.. I have two function that works well for the same task. Please guide me which is best and why?

```
public void restart()   
    {  
        Intent intent = getIntent();  
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);  
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);  
        finish();  
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade,R.anim.fade);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

**or**

```
public void restart()   
    {         
        onCreate();  
    }
```

Thanks In advance?

Comment: you should have studied the activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think  this is  a cleaner way for your requirement.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: +1. Thats what I thought, but unable to explain why its better than the other.

Comment: Thankss u..Can you please explain why not to use the second option

Comment: Basically when we save the state the `Activity` then we call  `onCreate(Bundle)` in case of rotation ...Other wise just `finish()` and call the intent again.

Comment: ok Tanmay... can u also explain the problem/error may arise in case of 'second opion' please??

Comment: @Gourav It will not end your current activity state as well as it will not remove the activity from the activity stack.

Answer (score 0):

Activities in the system are managed as an activity stack. When a new activity is started, it is placed on the top of the stack and becomes the running activity -- the previous activity always remains below it in the stack, and will not come to the foreground again until the new activity exits.

for more info see [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: Thanks Sir for your response, but when I close the running activity it get killed normally without showing an extra-ordinary behaviour(in case of second option)...

Answer (score 0):

This has been [posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```