# Android - restart part from onCreate

Tags: java, android

In my program, I'm creating shapes which are filled with random colors from a list. The colors are set in onCreate. I don't want it to have determined colors, but to change the colors multiple times. How do I 'restart' the onCreate part, so the colors are allocated again?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener
{       
            private Paint paint = new Paint();


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {   
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                       
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                           
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bg); 

                List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW);
                Collections.shuffle(numbers);

            }
}
```

Comment: When do you want to change the colors? When activity restarts, backs to foreground, click button...?

Comment: Check out these questions: [question1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150014/how-to-restart-the-oncreate-function), [question2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134249/android-activity-restart), may be this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have an animation part which I left out here, when the animation is done the colors should swap again. But if you tell me how I'd do it with a button I dispose it to an animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you, just put in your onResume or the method you want to restart oncreate from

```
onCreate(new Bundle());
```

for example by clicking a button like this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onCreate(new Bundle()); 
        }
});
```

Comment: Could you give a few more infomation about what to wrap in it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the trick, call this method

```
loadColors();
```

in oncreate and anywhere else u want

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener
{       
            private Paint paint = new Paint();


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {   
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                       
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                           
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bg); 

                loadColors();

            }



         private void loadColors(){
            List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.BLUE,                      
Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW);
                 Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to try your code, but I'm creating shapes in onCreate which are refered to `numbers`, so I get errors, if I'll take it out of the onCreate part. Is your way possible then?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the colors when you navigate from one activity to another then you can probably try wrapping up your code for changing the colors in a function and call that function in onResume() (one of the life cycle methods of an activity). onResume() will be called every time when your activity is loaded.