# Android: How to restart an instance?

Tags: java, android, instance, bundle

I want to restart an instance of my activity. Is it possible?

For example from an activity, I will go to another activity then when I go back to previous activity, all is new, no instance is saved.

I'm kinda new to android. thanks.

Comment: You mean when you go back to the initial activity by pressing the Back button or by calling `startActivity()`?

Comment: Hmm something like that, but how do I do it via startActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this old post could help you: [how do i restart an android activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by adding this line into my android manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

This is you declaring that you don't want to instantiate a new activity every time you start an intent of one. You can now reuse existing activities. Here's a link to the API document that explains this and other activity tweaks in the manifest file:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

This is an old question but hopefully this answer can help people still trying to figure this out.