# Onclick button language change in java android

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a way to implement change of language triggered by button onclick. I have created proper strings.xml in proper folders (for example res/values-en/) Here is my code of the button:

```
Button setEN_bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setEN);        
setEN_bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Locale locale_en = new Locale("en"); 
            Locale.setDefault(locale_en);
            Configuration config_en = new Configuration();
            config_en.locale = locale_en;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config_en, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    });
```

So basicly I change the locale with the onclick but the page doesn't refresh afterwards (why should it...:) ). Could somebody tell me how to refresh/reload the activity?

Thanx for help in advance.

Comment: Try calling setContentView() after changing the locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to call

```
view.invalidate();
```

on the view that you want redraw itself.

I'm not sure, if this will reload the Locales. If not, you could restart the Activity by creating a new Intent for itself:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Cheers

Comment: Thx for reply. I used this: v.invalidate() but it didnt work, so I tried with Intend but it wont work too. It seems that I can't call "this." inside the methods of the button listener. Any clue? Maybe I can pass it somehow into the method.

Comment: try using <Classname>.this if you are in a listener. For example "new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class)".

Comment: THANX Florian it worked. Here is the code:           Intent intent = new Intent(InvestWroclawActivity.this, InvestWroclawActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);

Comment: @Florian Barth do you know how to be in fragments with navigation drawer?

Comment: What do you mean with "how to be in fragments", Sultan?

Answer (score 1):

You can just start the activity by using

startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, CurrentActivity.class));
finish();
and finish the previous activity by using finish() method at the end in onclick method.

Comment: Yes. I did that in the comment above, thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling startActivity() and then finish(), you can call:

```
recreate(); // which is available from API Level 11.
```

I found this answer here which has another great ways to do it for lower API Levels:
[How do I restart an Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity)

Comment: That was easy, though I hope there is no down side with that method. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**First Method**

```
     String languageToLoad  = "en";
     Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
     Locale.setDefault(locale);
     Configuration config = new Configuration();
     config.locale = locale;
     context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

     Intent intent = new Intent(XYZ.this, XYZ.class);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//it will recreate it self with new language.
     startActivity(intent);
```

You need to restart your Activity after changing locale.

**Second Method**

```
 mLocale = new Locale("en");
          Locale.setDefault(mLocale); 
          Configuration config = new Configuration();
          config.locale = mLocale;
          getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
          getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
          MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//reset layout
```

but it will work on `api>=11`