# Android force new activity instance on home button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an application with three layouts.

According to the android documentation if you use the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag in the intent to return to the top activity, and the activity has it's launch mode set to 'standard' you should get a new instance of the activity. This will load the different layout that was set in preferences.

I get this behaviour in the android emulator running 4.2.2 without using any flags except `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. In my Nexus 7 also running 4.2.2 I never get a new instance and get the old layout unless I quit and restart the app.

I have tried adding 'android:launchMode="standard"' to the manifest and the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to the intent with no change.

Here is an extract from the manifest and the code snippet that should restart it.

```
<activity
android:name="org.billthefarmer.accordion.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:launchMode="standard"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
  <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Code from the class:

```
case android.R.id.home:
    // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
```

Is there a better way of achieving this or am I missing something?

Comment: you cannot override the default behaviour of home button on 4.0 (i guess) and above. its for security reasons.

Comment: Having spent a while writing this I tried changing the code to two addFlags() statements instead of one with ored flags and it worked. Even more inexplicable.

Comment: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` closes all activities on top of now launching activity (i.e., in your this particular case, closes all activities on top of MainActivity and does not reset MainActivity itself).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this method to your activity code:

```
public void reload() {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();

    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity)

Comment: @PareshMayani to reload your activity, instead using the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag

Comment: You should include such detail in your code to explain it properly.