# Changing of Application Locale does not take full effect in android?

Tags: android, setlocale

I am making an application in two languages English and in Indonesian.
For that i have created two strings file in res folder (values-en   and  values-in)

In one of my activity I select lanuage and change the locale.I am doing this using following code-

passing language id to this method-

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);

        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }
```

But after changing the language to indonesian strange thing happened. My Some of the text changed to indonesian and some changed to english.

for example- I have two Buttons (Submit and Upload Receipt) in activity.

SUBMIT btn has-
in english it's text is SUBMIT and in indonesian it is KIRIM

```
<string name="submit_btn_text">Submit</string>  for english
<string name="submit_btn_text">Kirim</string>   for indonesian
```

and UPLOAD RECEIPT btn has-
in english it's text is Upload Receipt and in indonesian it is Upload Penerimaan

```
<string name="upload_receipt">Upload Receipt</string>  for english
<string name="upload_receipt">Upload Penerimaan</string>   for indonesian
```

But in indonesian
Submit btn text chanes to **Kirim**
but Upload Receipt btn remain "Upload Receipt". It doesn't change to Upload Penerimaan.

How this is happened as other text chages as per locale.
Also I am facing same problem in all dialogs pop ups.Text remain in english in all dialogs.

What should be done?

Comment: have you tried restarting your activity?

Comment: Seems this approach may cause some problems: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/833647. Consider forcing a restart of your app on locale change.

Comment: @Ahmad-Yes I have restart activity.

Comment: @Aniket Bhosale: what android sdk you're working on? becuase I just have tested your scenario and it's working on my G Note 2 with JB (16).

Comment: @ahamad-My code is working for me also but some text is not displayed in indonesian language.

Comment: what do you mean by some text? you mean part of the text the textview is displaying? paste the text here.

Comment: read my updated questions for example part.

Comment: send me your email I am sending an apk

Comment: thanks, But I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try restarting your activity as suggested by other answers, check Ben's answer [How do I restart an Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3419987/488434)

```
public void reload() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();

    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);  
}
```