# Android: Two standalone applications integration

Tags: android-intent, integration

I have an existing application. Now I want to add some extra functionality into it. The extra functionality require some library. If i use the library in my app, the application size increases. So I want to make this extra functionality in a separate app and then integrate the new app to my existing app ( If i have some update for the existing app, then I have to download the whole app, which I don't want). I don't want both in one apk. Both should be standalone. From First application let say A, I want to call an activity in the new application B. I used intent.setComponent() and the activity of application B is called from A but I cannot get the result from Application B back in the first application.

Application A

```
public void onClickBtnToApplicationB(View v) {
    try {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("pakacagename","package.class");
        intent.setComponent(cn);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                 
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    //handle Exception
    } 
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE:
           handleResult(resultCode, intent);
           break;
    }
}

public void handleResult(int resultCode, Intent intentResult) {
    switch (resultCode) {
        case RESULT_OK:
            String Result = intentResult.getStringExtra("RESULT");
            // I need Results from Application B here..
            break;

         case RESULT_CANCELED:
            break;
    }
  }
```

Application B:
In application B, class 1 starts another activity for Result 2.class and get the results. After the results are received they are send back to the first application in handle result method'a putextras. So I need to get result in Application A's handleresult method which I didn't get.

```
Intent s = new Intent(1.this,2.class);
startActivityForResult(s, REQUEST_CODE_B);
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentResult) {     
    switch(requestCode){
        case REQUEST_CODE_B:
            handleResult(resultCode, intentResult);
    }
}

public void handleResult(int resultCode, Intent intentResult) {
    switch (resultCode) {
    case RESULT_OK:
        String scanResult = intentResult.getStringExtra("RESULT");
        Intent newintent = new Intent();
        newintent.putExtra("RESULT", scanResult);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, newintent);
        finish();
        break;

    case RESULT_CANCELED:
        break;
}
```

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing the code.

Comment: @BoD Code is available now

Comment: Is onActivityResult called?

Comment: What do you mean? ActivityResult in A is called by startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);  and in B with startActivityForResult(s, REQUEST_CODE_B);. Both request codes are positive integers.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that they are actually called in your case: did you put a log to make sure they are called?

Comment: @BoD Yeah after finishing Activity B, the OnActivityResult in A is not called. What could be the reason? it should be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `onActivityResult` on your Activity A is never called.

I bet it is related to how you call Activity B.

Instead of doing this:

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("pakacagename","package.class");
    intent.setComponent(cn);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                 
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

, you really should do it simply like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_B);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

with ACTION_B being a constant of the form `"com.mypackage.myapp.ACTION_B"` and that you have to declare in B's manifest like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.yourpackage.b.BActivity"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.ACTION_B" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem. Its result is almost the same. Previously after finishing the previous activity it show the Application A screen but now it show black screen after returning from Application B. I printout some text in onActivityResult but the logcat doesn't show anything which means the onActivityResult is not called. P.S: I am novice to Android.

Comment: if you can help me here. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 intent design you have to pass some data from the current intent to the new one, you could do something like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(yourcurrentactivity.this, yournewactivity.class);
                    // following line is an example of passing data to the new intent.
        i.putExtra(getString(R.string.str_selecteddialog), "1");
        startActivity(i);
        this.finish();
```

In the new intent that you have started in the onCreate you need to retrieve the data from the bundle:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        // Log.i(TAG, " 022:... we got some extras");
        str_selecteddialog = getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.str_selecteddialog));
```

Obviously, you have to put this type of code into both intents and reverse the activity names.  I would also use the try command to catch any issues with extras not being valued.  That condition has to exist at the beginning.

There are different types of put and get 'Extras' dependent on  variable types. To keep it a less confusing, I would also use one set of variables (Name Value Pairs, i.e. Extras) to pass to intent B and a different set for passing from Intent B to Intent A.

In addition you will want to have only one instance of each running at a time, this can be accomplished in two ways.  In the manifest within each off the above activities you could specify:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

or right before starting the other intent put this before startActivity:

```
Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Either or both of these will keep only one of each intent on the stack, instead of multiples of each.

In addition, just in case if you want to re-start the current intent see [Restarting the current intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity)

Hope this helps.