# Difference between recreating an Activity with recreate() method and startActivity(getIntent())

Tags: android, android-activity

I am more or less a beginner in android programming

My Question follows from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity).

As far as I can gather, there are mainly two ways to restart the same Activity I am in:

a)`Activity.recreate()` [ added after API 11 ]

b)

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
```

How does these two actually work? Are there any difference in the process they recreate the activity?

I believe there must be some difference between the way these two recreates the activity, because, I have seen that `recreate()` adds some default(junk?) values to the views in my activity.
Also, `recreate()` starts the new activity with a default black splash view

Comment: Well, b) is compatible with devices older than API level 11... ;)

Comment: Yes, thats up there in the post :P

Comment: It's a relevant difference, if you (like me) want to support AT LEAST Froyo (API level 8) devices.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Recreate** - (You can restore state of activity)
This results in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a configuration change -- the current instance will go through its lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it. *It also means ViewModel is not destroyed.*

The recreate() method acts just like a configuration change, so your onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods are also called, if applicable.

Very interesting read:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

vs

**Finish**
The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult().
and Started again as new activity on top of the stack

Comment: This is wrong. `onSaveInstanceState` is **NOT** called. It's only called if the system kills the activity.

Comment: @MartinKonecny - The docs are very specific that calling `recreate()` has the same effect as a configuration change: _"the current instance will go through its lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it."_. When that happens, `onSaveInstanceState()` **is** called, just as it is when the configuration changes (unless you've changed the default behavior via manifest flags).

Comment: thanks, vm not destroyed statement was helpful