# reload activity onTabChangeListener

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

i have a `TabHost` in my `MainActivity.java`. i want to reload my activity on condition which i give in code. Then i check internet connection because i want response from `WebService`. Now Question is That how i can reload my activity on tab change and want to run my `AsyncTask` which is in my `User.java`. `Onresume()` `OnWindowFocusedChange` did not work for me.

```
       mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (refreshSession.equals("yes")) {
                    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

                    // check for Internet status
                    if (isInternetPresent) {
                        // Internet Connection is Present
                        // make HTTP requests
                        /**
                         * what to do here ?????
                         */
                    } else {
                        // Internet connection is not present
                        // Ask user to connect to Internet
                        showAlertDialog(getParent(), "No Internet Connection", "You don't have internet connection.", false);
                    }

                    }
            }
        });
```

Thanx for any help :)

Comment: How to reload, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity

Comment: @Xcihnegn .. but where i should call this ? in which method ? OntabChangwListener ?