# How to call recreate()?

Tags: android, android-activity

I know this is probably extremely simple, but I just can not figure it out.

I'm trying to reload/recreate an activity after an action.  I know I could just use:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

But in reading through answers on the site I'm told to use 'recreate()' after 11 api.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

While using the [recreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) method works by doing

```
this.recreate()
```

It was only added in API level 11. If you want to include more devices you can check the API level and implement both the recreate method as well as

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

You can use both by making an if statement like...

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    //Code for recreate
    recreate();
} else {
    //Code for Intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Same comment above - Incredibly simple, thanks so much!  Thanks also for the additional explanation and if checking (employing your specifically in my project).

Comment: I'm performing some task inside a thread. I can't call recreate() method?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean? Have you tried mContext.recreate()?

Comment: how about recreate app without saved state? . For ex: user selects Date(game level) -> save it to SharedPref -> recreate activity based on updated SF value dismissing old state. (will create new question but I am afraid I will be bounce back this or similar thread)

Answer (score 2):

this.recreate() is all it takes. Stick that code inside a method that lives in the activity you want to reload. I have a project where this is tied to a button click but you can use it however you need to.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused by your question, you yourself answered the question in your answer. Call the method recreate directly...

From the documentation for `recreate()`:

> Cause this Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a configuration change -- the current instance will go through its lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it.

Call `recreate()` from within the activity code instead of

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

to restart the activity (after API 11 that is).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16467733/1946537) answer for a more generic recreate routine that works even for before API/SDK 11.

Comment: Thanks CPU!  Just wanted to start updating my project.  I was getting thrown off by 'this' for some reason.