# RecyclerView getting wrong position using onClick after searching

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-search

My RecyclerView is getting a filtered position after the list is filtered using the SearchView. This means that when the list item is clicked the information for the wrong item is displayed. I'm looking for a way to keep the original list position after filtering the list. Below is code for the RecyclerView Adapter and RecyclerView activity. Thanks in advance.

```
public class BrowseAdverts extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, AdvertsAdapter.OnAdvertListener, CountySheet.BottomSheetListener {

//Instance of the database helper class
private DatabaseHelper myDb;
private AdvertsAdapter mAdapter;
private List<Advert> advertsList = new ArrayList<>();
private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
private TextView noAdvertsView;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

//https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/
private BottomAppBar bottomAppBar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356604/how-to-switch-theme-for-an-activity
    setTheme(R.style.AppThemeToolbar);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse_adverts);

    coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout_browse);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvBrowseAdverts);
    noAdvertsView = findViewById(R.id.tvNoAdverts);
    noAdvertsView.setText("No Adverts");

    //https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/
    final FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
            (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_browse);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/modal-bottom-sheet
            CountySheet bottomSheet = new CountySheet();
            bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "countySheet");
        }

    });

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    //get all adverts from IS4447 SQLite tutorial
    advertsList.addAll(myDb.getAllAdverts());

    mAdapter = new AdvertsAdapter(this, advertsList, this);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    //add a default divider line between items
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    //https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/
    bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bar_browse);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab_browse);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, CreateAdvert.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    bottomAppBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, MyProfile.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }
    });

    toggleEmptyAdverts();
}

//to show the text view that says no adverts available when adverts table is empty
private void toggleEmptyAdverts() {

    //IS4447 Tutorial
    if (myDb.getAdvertCount() > 0) {
        noAdvertsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        noAdvertsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

//From search video
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzbvDJqXeJs
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    //added to add menu to bottom app bar
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bar_home, menu);

    return true;

}

//autogenerated when implement search
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}


//From this video bc the first one only had single strings https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9_hcfWVkIc
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    String userInput = newText.toLowerCase();
    ArrayList<Advert> newList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Advert advert: advertsList) {
        String name = advert.getAdvertName().toLowerCase();

        if (name.contains(userInput)){
            newList.add(advert);
        }
        mAdapter.setFilter(newList);
    }
    return true;

}

//has to be implemented when you implement the UserAdapter.Onclick
@Override
public void onAdvertClick(int position) {
    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUZcjZkJrvY
    //send parcel to new activity

    Intent intent = new Intent (this, AdvertDetail.class);
    intent.putExtra("selected_advert" , advertsList.get(position));
    startActivity(intent);

}
//https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

//Must be implemented for bottom sheet listener
@Override
public void onButtonClicked(String text) {
}

////https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.app_bar_home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Adapter

```
public class AdvertsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdvertsAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {

private Context context;
private List<Advert> advertList;
private OnAdvertListener mOnAdvertListener;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView advertName, advertCategory, advertId;
    OnAdvertListener onAdvertListener;


    public MyViewHolder(View view, OnAdvertListener onAdvertListener){
        super(view);

        advertName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        advertCategory = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCat);
        advertId = view.findViewById(R.id.tvId);


        this.onAdvertListener = onAdvertListener;
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onAdvertListener.onAdvertClick(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

public AdvertsAdapter(Context context, List<Advert> advertList, OnAdvertListener onAdvertListener) {

    this.context = context;
    this.advertList = advertList;
    this.mOnAdvertListener = onAdvertListener;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
 View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
         .inflate(R.layout.advert_list_row, parent, false);

 return new MyViewHolder(itemView, mOnAdvertListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Advert advert = advertList.get(position);

    holder.advertName.setText(advert.getAdvertName());
    holder.advertCategory.setText(advert.getAdvertCategory());
    holder.advertId.setText(advert.getAdvertId() + "");

}

public int getItemCount() {
    return advertList.size();
}

//From this video bc the tutorial one only had singular strings https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9_hcfWVkIc
public void setFilter(ArrayList<Advert> newList){
    advertList = new ArrayList<>();
    advertList.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public interface OnAdvertListener{
    void onAdvertClick (int position);
}
```