# How to Update an activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I am trying to update my activity whenever a variable is false inside a method.

I've tried this:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

But when I try to start my activity my app just stops and never shows the activity.

I've also tried calling onCreate method but when the variable is false my activity does not updates.

Please help or suggestions!

Comment: [Please check this link i think it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29722976/9055402)

Comment: I just tried that but my app just got frozen

Comment: Can you please describe on variable update what exactly you want, there might be other ways then this to achive your result.

Comment: I have a method that checks the variable value each time the user fails to login with fingerprint. And when it fails for the third the app should hide and show certain imageviews.

Answer (score 1):

It's very bad practice to recreate activity when any variable changes. If you need to change some values of some variables just make a method that would encapsulate logic of such change or use MutableLiveData class for observing data change. Check [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) from Google about LiveData

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
startActivity(getIntent());
finish();
```

instead of :

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Comment: This time my activity did open but it was never updated it only updates when I set my app in background and open it again.

Comment: make your activity boolean variable static so it maintains the previous state.

Comment: I still can't get this code to work, only if I set the app in background and then opening it gain!