# How to get parent activity reference in fragment constructor?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `GameActivity` `Activity` one of whose methods is:

```
/** Show "Game is finished" dialog. */
public void showFinishedDlg(int bodyMsgRes) {
    GameFinishedDlgFragment.newInstance(bodyMsgRes).show(
            this.getFragmentManager(), "finished_dlg");
}
```

This is the dialog fragment that method creates:

```
public class GameFinishedDlgFragment extends DialogFragment {

    static GameFinishedDlgFragment newInstance(int bodyMsgRes) {

        GameFinishedDlgFragment frag = new GameFinishedDlgFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("body_msg", bodyMsgRes);
        frag.setArguments(bundle);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int bodyMsgRes = args.getInt("body_msg");

        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(bodyMsgRes)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.new_game, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // PROBLEM HERE. TODO: Restart GameActivity
                        this.parentActivity.recreate();
                    }
                });

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make the `onClick` of the dialog's button restart `GameActivity`, but I can't figure out how to get the reference to that activity instance.

If I try:

```
this.parentActivity.recreate();
```

the compiler tells me:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'parentActivity'
```

Comment: Create a local variable of Activity type .... pass your activity from onclick which you will get in you new instance method ...init local variable and use

Comment: @koutuk I'm very confusde by your comment. Create a local variable where? In `GameActivity.showFinishedDlg()` or inside `OnClick`? You "pass" things to something, not "from" something as you say.

Comment: create local variable lets say "Activity localref" in GameFinishedDlgFragment class..... now when ever you call newInstance method/constructor pass another variable along with you message...

Comment: i have posted answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please override the onAttach method of the fragment.
The incoming activity param is your parent activity.

lifecycle methods of fragment:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_1_-_creating_a_fragment/Images/fragment_lifecycle.png

official reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)

or just call getActivity() at everywhere you code, AFTER onAttach has completed! Calling it, before onAttach it gives NULL

(read comments below)

Comment: I like this solution the best, but if in `GameFinishedDlgFragment.OnAttach()` I assign the activity to a field `this.parentActivity`. Then I try to reference it with `this.parentActivity.recreate()` inside `onClick`. The problem is that `this` refers to the `AlertDialog.Builder` not to `GameFinishedDlgFragment`. See the code in my post: it will be clear to you.

Comment: what about: GameFinishedDlgFragment.this.getActivity() ?

Comment: Then compiler says "cannot resolve method `recreate()`". I'm not sure what `this` refers to in this case.

Comment: by the way, what is recreate? I really hope you are not trying to recreate the Activity ! check this out please:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity

Comment: But your way with `getActivity()` worked just fine. I was just wondering if there's a Java trick to make `this` refer to the correct thing.

Comment: Yes I'm following this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10453257/797744) to restart `GameActivity`.

Comment: I don`t understand , but the Fragment.this.getActivity().recreate() worked for me! No compiler error!
GameFinishedDlgFragment.this is the currently running instance of the GameFinishedDlgFragment class. Did you tried to cast for an Activity ?

Comment: Yes that worked. What you told me to write before was `GameFinishedDlgFragment.this.getActivity()`. But I can just call `getActivity().recreate()` and it works.

Comment: I`m happy it`s worked ! If you think I help to solve it, please accept my answer and I adding a @read comments below@ line :D

Comment: @NewWorld No idea why you'd choose this answer as correct but I guess you know better. Somebody (@Karoly) needs to learn English though :)

Comment: @NewWorld this "answered 54 mins ago", mine "answered 1 hour ago". Both suggest `getActivity.recreate()`. But nevermind. No problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go:

```
getActivity().recreate();
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, it compiles now. I didn't know about `getActivity()`.

Comment: @NewWorld you're welcome :) mark this answer as correct if your problem was resolved.

Comment: Is there a reason that you do the casting and check that it's a specific `instanceof`? I could write just `getActivity()).recreate()` and it works.

Comment: @NewWorld this is just a safety check in case the fragment is used by another activity which does not have that specific method.

Comment: But all instances of [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) have this method.

Comment: @NewWorld oops you're right. Somehow I thought you're using a custom method. I'll update my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class GameFinishedDlgFragment extends DialogFragment { 
    private Activity localref;
   static GameFinishedDlgFragment newInstance(int bodyMsgRes,Activity actref)       {
         this.localref=actref;
        GameFinishedDlgFragment frag = new GameFinishedDlgFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("body_msg", bodyMsgRes);
        frag.setArguments(bundle);
        return frag;
    } 

    @Override 
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int bodyMsgRes = args.getInt("body_msg");

        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction 
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(bodyMsgRes)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.new_game, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // PROBLEM HERE. TODO: Restart GameActivity 
                       localref.recreate();
                    } 
                }); 

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it 
        return builder.create();
    } 
}
```