# How to relaunch current activity with new data from notification click intent on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification

I'm using the following intent with a notification and the issue is that if the current activity is the same as the intent nothing happens. How do I open the same activity with the new data?

```
intent = new Intent(context, PackViewActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("pid", pack_id);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Here is the details fromt he Manaifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".PackViewActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"/> //I've also tried singleInstance with no success.
```

Currently everything works fine unless the current activity is `PackViewActivity`. In that case nothing happens.

Comment: try this `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` instead of `CLEAR_TASK`

Comment: See the following post, see if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity

Comment: @VivekMishra That has not made a difference :( thanks though

Comment: have you started activity after that?

Comment: @VivekMishra Yes, the activity is already open in this case;

Comment: I mean to say have you called `startActivity(intent)` after you defined your intent?

Comment: @VivekMishra No, this is a pending intent for a notification click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Vivek mentioned, use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`. Now, if your activity is already running the new intent will be delivered in `onNewIntent()`. That is where you should put your intent reading code. Also, get rid of `android:launchMode` in your activity manifest description since it brings a lot of problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

If the required activity is already in foreground then you need not to push a notification. Alternatively you can register the activity as a listener to the service or activity class which pushes the notification through NotificationManager. Then handle the notification appropriately.