# Restart Android app to specific activity

Tags: java, android

I want to restart my Android app, but I want it to go to a specific activity after the app restart.

I am currently using this code to re launch my app, but it starts back to the first activity. I need it to go to another specific activity.

I made a settings page in my application where users can choose their own app colors. After choosing a color, i need to restart all activities to apply the new theme that the user chose.

code I am using to restart app to first activity:

```
Intent startActivity = new Intent();
            startActivity.setClass(ProfileSettingsActivity.this,ProfileSettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(startActivity);
            finish();
```

Comment: I don't want to know why do you need this, but you may want `Activity#recreate()` method.

Comment: You may call recreate() method.
For more info, please see this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16467733/5371335).

Comment: Have you considered using Shared Preferences?

Answer (score 0):

easy

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ANOTHER_SPECIFIC_ACTIVITY.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Don't just write some code. Explain what you've done.

Comment: I need the app to reload, not opening a new activity. I need a full app reload to apply my changes..

Comment: "I am currently using this code to re launch my app, but it starts back to the first activity. I need it to go to another specific activity." i put ANOTHER_SPECIFIC_ACTIVITY so you can replace it with yours. it is not a good thing to say "full app". you can replace your start activity so that your app restarts and begin fresh.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreate()` of your first activity, check for whatever conditions you want, and then based on those conditions launch the intent for your specific activity before the `setContentView()` is called in the first activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(CONDITION_1) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityA.class));
    } else if(CONDITION_2) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing all activities and launch the new one with Flags?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NEW_ACTIVITY.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Doing this, you are clearing all activities previously created and launch `NEW_ACTIVITY.class` with the new configuration.