# Does recreate() allow to modify intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to relaunch current activity with new intent. Since calling self with new intent would create an infinite loop, so was trying to do via [recreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10453257/865220). But does recreate allow to update the intent?

Comment: Yes, you can relaunch the activity using `recreate()`. But what do you mean by `update the intent`?

Comment: When I called initially I did this `intent.putExtra(OverlayActivity.VIDEOID, 1);`, now I need to do `intent.putExtra(OverlayActivity.VIDEOID, 2);`

Comment: Intent has a property where you can pass the data along, but the same is not with `recreate()` method. It just creates an activity, with a new instance.

Comment: so basically it means I have to do it the old way ? like this:  `Intent intent = getIntent(); intent.putExtra(OverlayActivity.VIDEOID, 2); finish(); startActivity(intent);`

Comment: If you just want to relaunch activity use `recreate()`. Otherwise Intent way would work

Answer (score 1):

[**`recreate ()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) will not update your **`KEY-PAIR`** .

> The system remembers that it existed such that if the user navigates
>   back to it, the system creates a new instance of the activity using a
>   set of saved data that describes the state of the activity when it was
>   destroyed. The saved data that the system uses to restore the previous
>   state is called the **`"instance state"`** and is a collection of key-value
>   pairs stored in a Bundle object.

So, For this problem You should use **`Intent intent = getIntent()`**

Answer (score 0):

`does recreate allow to update the intent?`

No,`Intent` has a property where you can pass the data along, but the same is not with `recreate()` method. It just creates an activity, with a new instance.

So through recreate() method you won't be able to update the **`Key-Value`** pair