# start actvity but restart if already running

Tags: android

How do I check if an activity is running already and if so, restart the activity?

Currently, I'm using this code to start the activity. However, if the activity NewActivity is already running, I would like to restart it (or send a broadcast)?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STRING, true);
startActivity(intent);
return;
```

Comment: You should not do so, if there is no such specific requirement. Instead declare the `launchMode` of activity to `singleTop` and receive updated intent in `onNewIntent()`method and update existing Activity.

Comment: Great. Didn't know we could do that. I'll try doing that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If `NewActivity` is already running then simply use this trick to restart.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STRING, true);
 finish();
 startActivity(intent);
```

Better you can follow this: [How do I restart an Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity)

Comment: finish() wouldn't work since I'm not starting the activity from NewActivity itself. The NewActivity is being started from a Service.

Answer (score 1):

if your current activity is NewActivity and you want to restart it self than use

recreate();

If currently any other activity is on foreground than use

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
 intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STRING, true);
startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK will clear all other activities available in activity stack, whereas FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK will start a new task for you NewActivity