# How to start same Activity with new data when android:launchMode="singleInstance"?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I am trying to do it like :

```
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityRating.this, ActivityRating.class).putExtra("Type", AppConstant.PRODUCT_REVIEW).putExtra("Id", review.getId()).putExtra("paramStore", mVendor));
finish();
```

Activity close but it didn't open again? with this code.

I found the Solution

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityRating.this, ActivityRating.class).putExtra("Type", AppConstant.PRODUCT_REVIEW).putExtra("Id", review.getId()).putExtra("paramStore", mVendor);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restart an Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity)

Comment: Why are you using single instance launch mode? This isn't necessary and is the root of your problem. This is one of the reasons why you should not use the special launch modes.

Comment: Why do you want to restart your `Activity`? Can't you just reinitialize it internally? There should be no reason to restart it like this

Answer (score 0):

implement  this method

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

}
```